# How to catch the error in Angular2, Angular 2 error: Unhandled Promise rejection

Tags: angular

I have a header.component.ts which uses the service.js. the service.js will detect any change on the balanceObservable object and then change the header.compnoent.ts behaviour. as show in the code, service will reject(error) if there is an error, but component.ts can't receive the error but instead giving a `zone.js:484 Unhandled Promise rejection`

[image]

service.js

```
  public balanceObservable = new Subject<string[]>();

  refreshBalance (address) {
      var self = this;
      return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        self.getBalance(self.wallet.address, function (error, result) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          } else {
            self.balanceObservable.next(result);
            resolve(result);
            }
        })
      })
    }
```

header.component

```
  watchBalance(){
    var self = this;
     const subscription = this.service.balanceObservable.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log('watchBalance',result);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log('watchBalance err',err);
      }
    )
 }
```

Later I tried to catch the error in catch  .

```
this.service.balanceObservable.subscribe((result) => {},)
.catch(e => console.log("reject: " + e));
```

but also come with error `Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.`

Answer (score 0):

service.js

```
  public balanceObservable = new Subject<string[]>();

  refreshBalance (address) {
      var self = this;
      return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        self.getBalance(self.wallet.address, function (error, result) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          } else {
            self.balanceObservable.next(result);
            resolve(result);
            }
        })
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('Here we catch the promise error');
      })
    }
```

header.component

```
  watchBalance(){
    var self = this;
     const subscription = this.service.balanceObservable.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log('watchBalance',result);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Argument of type '(e: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<string[]>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: I've corrected the code. You should also import Observable and of operator

Comment: I tried, but still the exception shows up in the console, the code doesn't seem to catch it.

Comment: Ok, got it (at once)) Still a question whether you use promise from refreshBalance at all? Or only subscribed to Subject? I will update my answer in two minutes ...updated